# how to start a shell that will display login / password prompt?

Tags: linux, shell, login

lets say that I have a program that is running in tty1 displaying a menu, one of the entry of this menu is to have access to the shell, which command can I start to be able to have a prompt asking for login / password ?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean [`login`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/login.1.html)?

Comment: maybe but starting login (without any options) doesn't ask for login nor password, I just have the cursor blinking, and that's all

Comment: You should make sure that the program that invokes login, is secure: no way to break out.

Comment: Ok, do you mean that the system must trust the program ? how do I say to the system that this program is secure ?

Comment: What user is this menu running as?

Comment: The menu is run under the root user

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `login` command is what I need to display a normal login / password prompt. The trick is to start the command by using `exec`

> The login program is used to establish a new session with the system.
>   It is normally invoked automatically by responding to the "login:"
>   prompt on the user's terminal. login may be special to the shell and
>   may not be invoked as a sub-process. When called from a shell, login
>   should be executed as **exec login** which will cause the user to exit
>   from the current shell (and thus will prevent the new logged in user
>   to return to the session of the caller). Attempting to execute login
>   from any shell but the login shell will produce an error message.

Source : https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ulogin.htm

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]! **:-)** Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: And start it as root, as `login(1)` is not setuid. Have you considered using `su(1)`?

Comment: @mosvy thank you, my menu app is running under root, so it works, thanks for you tip